# Android Realm not saving the variable in database

Tags: realm, realm-list, realm-migration

I created a modal class

```
@RealmClass
class Temp extends RealmObject{

    var1
    var2
    var3

    getter setter of all above variables.
}
```

and save this data to database

```
Temp temp = database.createObject(Temp.class);
temp.setVar1("var1");
temp.setVar1("var2");
temp.setVar1("var3");
database.commitTransaction();
```

Saved the code and run the application and this worked.

After few days i added a new variable in class Temp and try to save it in the database, there was no error 
but when i fetch data from database it always show the new variable (var3) null.

Comment: Did you fetch the data from the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your model class should extend `RealmObject` that is:

```
class Temp extends RealmObject {

}
```

Comment: @RealmClass
public class ChatModel extends RealmObject{
 
}

Comment: Yes my class is extending RealmObject. Can you when the scenario comes when realm doesn't saves the variable in a database.

Comment: If `var3` is a string, and the field isn't marked `@Required`, `null` is a perfect legal value.

Comment: It is showing syntax error in @Required (Required cannot be resolved to a 
 type)

Comment: Please share the model class - otherwise it is going to be guesswork only.

Comment: @RealmClass
public class ChatModel extends RealmObject{

Comment: Can you share the rest of the class?

Answer (score 0):

you need begin transaction in front, or use executeTransaction where both begin and commit transaction is handled.